# Overwriting data with HDF5 lite

Tags: c++, file-io, hdf5, scientific-computing

I'm working on a project with HDF5 Lite, and I'm having some trouble writing to an already existing dataset. What I'm currently doing is calling H5LTmake_dataset to accomplish this, but this causes an error. Currently, the error I'm getting is from H5L.c and it is saying that the dataset name already exists:

```
#006: ..\..\src\H5L.c line 1674 in H5L_link_cb(): name already exists
major: Symbol table
minor: Object already exists
```

This is true, but what I want to do is overwrite the data that's already there.  Does anyone have any ideas as to how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After a little bit of research, I found that is was just as easy to call the native HDF5 write function:

```
DataSet * dataset_int = new DataSet(file->openDataSet("/group1/dataset1")); 
dataset_int->write(array, PredType::NATIVE_INT);
```

Hope this helps people :)